# Optimize laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, indexing

I have two tables

`click_logs` has 100k records with columns:

1. id
2. message_id --index
3. url

`tracking_logs` has 10 mil records with columns:

1. id
2. message_id --index
3. campaign_id --foreign key to campaigns table

I'm currently getting the top 5 clicks with this laravel query:

```php
 $records = ClickLog::select(DB::raw(DB::getTablePrefix() . 'click_logs.*, count(*) as `aggregate`'))
    ->leftJoin('tracking_logs', 'tracking_logs.message_id', '=', 'click_logs.message_id')
    ->where('tracking_logs.campaign_id', '=', $this->id);

 $records = $records->groupBy('click_logs.url')
    ->orderBy('click_logs.id', 'desc')
    ->take(5);
```

raw query :

```sql
SELECT '_click_logs'.\*, count(*) AS aggregate FROM '_click_logs' 
        LEFT JOIN 'tracking_logs' ON 'tracking_logs'.'message_id' = '_click_logs'.'message_id' 
        WHERE 'tracking_logs'.'campaign_id' = ? 
        GROUP BY '_click_logs'.'url' ORDER BY '_click_logs'.'id' DESC LIMIT 5
```

EXPLAIN Table

[explain table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHObd.png)

Its currently taking 0.7s to 0.5s

Can this query builder be more optimize to get faster result?

Comment: first try to `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to better understand impact of your query. I suppose it takes a lot of time while grouping (`GROUP BY ...` statement) `url` field which has no index. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: could you share your table schemes

Comment: `tracking_logs` needs `INDEX(campaign_id, message_id)`.  After I see the CREATEs and EXPLAIN, I may have more advice.

Comment: @RickJames  I had added the image for explain table.

Comment: And the CREATEs?